# click event fires twice (not by jQuery)

Tags: javascript, events, click

I wrote small piece of code which should toggle reporting box on my page. It's one function attached to click event of 2 elements (well - I know, the solution is to separate this function into 2, but I want to understand problem with this function). The problem is that at closing function is fired twice and box don't want to disappear.

```js
function overlayInit() {
    var rep = document.createElement("div");
    rep.setAttribute('id','reportbug');
    document.body.appendChild(rep);
    toggleReporter();
}

function toggleReporter(ev) {
    var e = document.getElementById('reportbug');

    if(ev)
    {
        console.log(ev);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('notarget');
    }

    if (e.hasClass('collapsed'))
    {
        console.log('Extending');
        e.removeClass('collapsed');
        e.addClass('expanded');
        e.removeEventListener('click',toggleReporter);

        e.innerHTML = 
            '<h5>Wyraź swoją opinię na temat tej strony</h5>'+
            '<button class="text" id="closeRep">[× zamknij]</button>'+
            '<form action="reportbug" method="post">'+
            '<textarea name="cont" style="width:100%;font:14px Verdana,sans-serif;height:100px;">'+
            '</textarea><br />'+
            '<input type="submit" value="Wyślij" />'+
            '</form>'
        ;

        // Double fired
        document.getElementById('closeRep').addEventListener('click',toggleReporter);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Collapsing');
        if ( e.hasClass('expanded') )
        {
            console.log('Removing events');
            e.removeClass('expanded');
            document.getElementById('closeRep').removeEventListener('click',toggleReporter);
        }
        e.addClass('collapsed');
        e.addEventListener('click',toggleReporter);
        e.innerHTML = 'Wyraź opinię';
    }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", overlayInit, false);
```

Problem occurs on FF10.0.2 on Ubuntu.

I discovered that 2 fired events have one difference - `event.eventPhase` (first `2`, second `3`).

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); actually worked ^^

Comment: e.stopPropagation() is not present in IE instead window.event.cancelBubble = true;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know what I should write here other than directing to [quirksmode - events order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)...

It is because of the way javascript events are defined by the W3C - they *bubble* up **and** down the DOM tree upon to the element that captures the event.

So, either use jQuery which handles it for you, or use `e.stopPropagation()` or (as Sheikh said) `window.event.cancelBubble = true`.

Comment: The question is "not by jQuery" but I found this useful nonetheless 
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/